# Magento 2. Remove column from customer grid (admin)

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, customer-grid

How does one **remove** a given column from `customer grid` (admin) ?

**Edit:**

I wish to **remove** the column not **hide** it.

**Edit 2**

Setting the following is not working.

```
'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,                
'is_used_in_grid' => false,
'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
'is_filterable_in_grid' => false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for me it was the confirmation(Confirmed email).

I've updated the `confirmation` attribute setting the following

```
'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,                
'is_used_in_grid' => false,
'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
'is_filterable_in_grid' => false
```

Now this did not work on it's own and I'm not sure that it contributed to my solution, I'm stating it though cause it might be relevant.

What I did was extend the `ui_component` itself.

**etc/module.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Company_Module" setup_version="0.0.2">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="confirmation" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Confirmation" sortOrder="130">
            <settings>
                <controlVisibility>false</controlVisibility>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Confirmed email</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Note the **controlVisibility** node.
More information about it can be found here

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-column.html

Comment: I tried your code, but it doesn't worked

Comment: @senthil It has been a long time since I looked into this. Yet I remember it working. 
You can try and make another thorough check to see that all steps were correctly applied. Also check that cache is cleared.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the company column in grid.

**view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
       <column name="billing_company">
             <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
     </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, however I could use additional context / explanation to help those less familiar with what this file is and what is happening.

Comment: Ok thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

After you login and open customer grid, just follow this screenshot

[image]

Comment: I wish to remove the column, not hide it.

Comment: @vitoriodachef: Have you solution?

Comment: @kranthi check the accepted answer

Comment: @vitoriodachef: i want to remove it grammatically(Need to remove column condition based).

Answer (score 1):

Although, it is not recommended to make changes in the Magento's tables directly, but since Magento does not provide attributes management in the community edition, you can try this solution.

1. Check the **`attribute_id`** in **`eav_attribute`** table for the attribute which you want to remove from the grid.
2. Search for the same **`attribute_id`** in **`customer_eav_attribute`** table and change the values of **`is_used_in_grid`**,    **`is_visible_in_grid`**, **`is_filterable_in_grid`** and   **`is_searchable_in_grid`** fields to 0.

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: So I didn't go directly in the database with the hammer. I've used the customer setup and did a update attribute with the changes you suggested. Also did a reindex. It's not working. It's still there.

Comment: Please check in the database table whether your setup script made any changes in the table or not?

Comment: I confirm that changes were applied