# Magento 2: Display some colunms in the grid customer according to group

Tags: magento2, attributes, grid, overrides

**I have created a new menu so that when clicking on all customer, I have two sub menu:**

> local and export

And I want to have in the local grid the list of customers that belong to group 1 and in the export grid the list of customers that belong to group2.

But I still don't know how to proceed. Another question I tried to override the grid customer_listing with this link

[Magento 2. Remove column from customer grid (admin)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220909/magento-2-remove-column-from-customer-grid-admin?rq=1)

But with no result, So how to do that properly please and how to duplicate this customer_listing for local because the attributes in the grid 1 are not the same as in grid 2.

So please I am really lost i want to know what to do step by step.

Comment: you can create separate 2 grid instade of overing this default one. And you need to fildet the grid collection before it load.

Comment: ok i have this approach but how to that please step by step i still a biginner :(

Comment: how to collect data according to group id  ???

Comment: https://magecomp.com/blog/filter-ui-component-grid-collection-magento-2/ this link help you to filter grid collection. So you just need to create grid first.

Comment: thanks very much vor replaying i ill try that

Comment: <item name="status" xsi:type="string">*</item> i want to filter with group_id but the type is smallint not a string so how to change that

Comment: ok not working still have all the list and a loader  continously :(