# How to hide the Customer column in Reports > Customers > Order Count in Magento2?

Tags: magento2

How to hide the `Customer` column in `Reports > Customers > Order Count`?

`Reports > Customers > Order Count` is this screen:
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/reports/customer-reports.html#order-count

And I also need to hide the column in its CSV. How to do it?

In which file is the column `Customer` added or defined?

Is it possible to hide and show the column depending on some condition of the admin user in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The customer order reports grid columns are rendered from `"reports_report_customer_orders_grid.xml"` file. You can find this layout file in the following path: `Magento\Reports\view\adminhtml\layout\reports_report_customer_orders_grid.xml`

You can comment or remove the below block so that you can hide the customer column in that grid.

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.report.grid.columnSet.name" as="name">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer</argument>
                <argument name="sortable" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">name</argument>
                <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">name</argument>
                <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
                <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
            </arguments>
</block>
```

If you want to dynamically show/hide the column based on a condition, then you can try the below method.

All the blocks of `"reports_report_customer_orders_grid.xml"` layout is rendered in the following class "`Magento\Reports\Controller\Adminhtml\Report\Customer\Orders.php`".

```
$this->_view->renderLayout(); // this is the line responsible for render all blocks.
```

You can override the controller and add a custom condition like below code:

```
public function execute()
{
    $this->_initAction()->_setActiveMenu(
        'Magento_Reports::report_customers_orders'
    )->_addBreadcrumb(
        __('Customers by Number of Orders'),
        __('Customers by Number of Orders')
    );
    $this->_view->getPage()->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Order Count Report'));
    //custom code starts here
    if($customCondition) {
        $this->_view->getLayout()->unsetElement('adminhtml.report.grid.columnSet.name'); //This line of code will unset the "customer" column from that grid
    }
    //custom code ends here
    $this->_view->renderLayout();
}
```

This is the code is enough for removing customer column in Export CSV/XML functionality also.

Comment: thank you! i will try your answer.

Comment: `$this->_view->getLayout()->unsetElement('adminhtml.report.grid.columnSet.name');` worked perfectly. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below set of codes under the customer column.

```
<item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
```

reference [Magento 2. Remove column from customer grid (admin)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220909/magento-2-remove-column-from-customer-grid-admin)